# Any low cost solution for using Windows as home NAT router?

Tags: windows, networking, router, nat

Long story short:

I need to replace a D-Link home router with Windows PC for some reason. How can do it without paying $500 for a Windows Server license?

---

Full story:

I've been a Linux & Mac user for my whole life and I have my own computers in office. Recently the upper-level decided to further enforce monitoring effort, by forcing all of us to install 3 different set of monitoring softwares on computer, otherwise the network access will be blocked. Needless to say, there are only Windows version available.

As a full stack coder, I'm not going to change my coding workflow. I'm planning to set a spared old Windows PC as guise, to satisfy those control freaks.

Problem is, I've no idea how the monitoring software works; I don't know whether it's proactively connecting to some server, or passively listening to some TCP/UDP ports on the given static private IP address. I'm now using a cheap D-Link home router to share the network link to my two working machines, and I need to enable port forwarding for HTTP access to my woking machine, so I can't just put the Windows PC behind NAT and set it to DMZ.

So, I need to setup a NAT server on Windows to share Ethernet connection to another Ethernet NIC, for two of my own computers. I fully aware how to set up packet forwarding and IP masquerading on Linux system, but I've no idea how to do that on Windows. I tried to search on internet, but after few hours reading I can only find 3 different types of solutions regarding this topic:

- Set up NAT in Hyper-V. If I understand it correctly, it works only for internal routing between guest OS and host OS. This is not what I wanted since I need packet forwarding between two physical NICs, and I don't think it would be a good idea to run a Linux guest OS solely for this purpose.
- Set up TCP forwarding using `netsh` command, but seems this only works for TCP but not UDP. I need to forward UDP too for my project under development so this doesn't work for me too.
- Install Windows Server. Yeah it works but it costs $500+ for a minimal essential licensing.

Is there any other 3rd party tools for this ? I don't mind paying for software but $500 is a little bit too much.

Answer (score 0):

Windows used to come with the ["Internet Connection Sharing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Connection_Sharing) feature for a very long time, providing NAT and DHCP service. It seems this is still available in Windows 10:

1. Open "Network Connections" via `ncpa.cpl`
2. Right-click the network adapter with Internet access, choose "Properties".
3. Open the "Sharing" tab and enable "Allow other network users to connect through this computer’s Internet connection".

ICS supports port-forwarding (both manual and UPnP IGD), but it does not support customizing the IP address range. I suspect it is also IPv4-only. The original Windows XP Firewall was actually built on top of this service.